# "He looked at her with a hurt expression" - Who has the hurt expression?

Tags: meaning-in-context, attachment-ambiguity

There is a sentence like below.

> He looked at her with a hurt expression.

I don't know whether **he** has a hurt expression or **she** (her) has a hurt expression.

Answer (score 3):

> He looked at her with a hurt expression

**with a hurt expression** is a prepositional phrase: it can modify a verb or a noun.

If it modifies the verb, it describes the way in which he is looking (the expression on his face). It wouldn't really work with **talk**, because **with at hurt expression** can't really describe the way you talk... but it does work with **look**.

If it modifies a noun, it functions like an adjective- it can either be descriptive (she is **tall**) or determining (the **tall** woman). Neither of these works with **her**: for descriptive usage, the noun must be a subject form **she**, and it is not necessary to use a determining form with **her** because, in order to use the pronoun, we must already know who it refers to.

In this case, therefore, it can only modify the verb, describing the way that he is looking at her.

The following sentence could be interpreted both ways, because **the man** can be followed by a determining with-clause- one that defines which particular man we are talking about:

> He looked at [the man with a hurt expression] - *with-phrase applies to **the man***
>   He looked at [the man] with a hurt expression - *with-phrase applies to **looked***

Comment: I noticed that all the examples I used in my answer had nouns/noun phrases and not pronouns (this is that holy **** moment for me). I wasn't aware that the presence of "her" in OP's example is a key element that makes the sentence unambiguous. Great answer!

Comment: It could be ambiguous with an indefinite pronoun, eg _He wanted someone with a zest for life_  (though it's hard to come up with an example of a modifier that makes sense both ways).

Comment: @ColinFine Yes, the reason that 'her' doesn't work is that it's already definite, so you can't use it with a determining with-clause. When you use an indefinite pronoun, you can definitely use it with a determining with-clause. ... though you can say "she who must be obeyed"...

Comment: @JavaLatte: You can really only say _she who must be obeyed_ because it is a set phrase. The original was not only 19th century and literary, but a special use anyway: the novel is called _She_.

Answer (score 0):

> **He  looked  at  her  with  a hurt expression**

I  believe  that  the sentence  is  not  ambiguous  since the  verb look  at  looked holds  good for **her**  ( object) and **with  a  hurt  expression**(prepositional phrase)

He looked  at her  with a hurt expression.

This  can  be analyzed  this way:

Who did he  look  at  ?- her

How did  he look  at  her?- with a  hurt expression.

In any  way  we analyse  this  sentence, the  prepositional phrase which is  an adjunct  refers  back to  He  but  not  her.

So there  is  no ambiguity  of  who  has a  hurt expression.It is  undoubtedly  he  who  has  a  hurt expression.

The  sentence  is  not  ambiguous  because  of  the  pronoun  her. If  it  is an indefinite  pronoun or  a  noun , it  becomes ambiguous.

> **He  looked  at  somebody  with a hurt  expression**

It  may  mean that either  he has  a hurt  expression or  somebody  has  a  hurt  expression.

> **He  looked  at the  stranger  with  a  hurt expression**

This  sentence  means  that  either  he has a  hurt  expression or the  stranger  has  a hurt expression.

Comment: The word "because" is generally used to introduce an argument for a proposition, not simply restate the proposition.